# CSS doesn't load after publishing project

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I published a website in visual studio and then added in IIS but when i tried to navigate my website, i noticed that the CSS didn't load. I found some articles here saying to change the path of the css location but it didnt work for me.
when i monitor my website with google chrome web developper, it let me see what isn't working, i get the error GET http://localhost:60600/Css/Master.css 404 (Not Found)
Please find here my MasterPage.Master file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
<title>TheSite</title>
<link href="../Css/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div class="Header">
<div class="Header_div">
        <div class="Header_Logo">
        Automation Tools
        </div>


        <div class="Header_Menu">   
        <ul>
        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>></li>               

        <li><a href="Troubleshoot.aspx">Troubleshoot</a>></li>               

        <li><a href="">contact</a>></li>            
        <li><a href="">Help</a>></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
  </div>
  </div>





    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

my css file is located at "C:\inetpub\WebSite\Css\Master.css"
i changed to link serveral way but it didn't work

```
<link href="../Css/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Css/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Css/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="file:///C:/inetpub/WebSite/Css/Master.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

when i use the link "file:///C:/inetpub/WebSite/Css/Master.css", i get the error "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/inetpub/WebSite/Css/Master.css"

Can someone help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried with `href="~/Css/Master"`

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the extension .CSS to the MIME TYPES and REQUEST FILTERING features in IIS.